# Swift UITapRecognizer steals the tap from an UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

If I use UITapGestureRecognizer, my UITableView objets does not get taps, but the recognizer works well.

Tap recognizer init:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapBackground)) 
menuBackground?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Windows hierarchy:

```
menuBackground?.addSubview(menuWindow!)
menuWindow?.addSubview(menuList!)
```

It works well:

```
@objc func tapBackground(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

  let tapLocation = sender.location(in: menuBackground)
  if !menuWindow!.frame.contains(tapLocation) {
      closeMenu()
  }
}
```

It works well if i **do not use** the tap recognizer, but if i use that, this function does nothing. Why?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print( indexPath.row )
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add gesture recognizer delegate and also, your should add your UItapGestureRecognizer in the cellForRowAt.

```
 func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: finally i found the solution.  tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false